# Free casino link appearing on Wordpress site

Tags: wordpress

I have recently set up a Wordpress site but I am getting a ' free online casino' link on my site which I can't get rid of.

I have tried looking in the header.php but I can't seem to find it. All of my plugins and Wordpress are up to date. Have I been hacked? How can I delete this link?

I have attached a screen shot (see below).

header.php

```
<?php
/**
 * The Header for our theme.
 *
 * Displays all of the <head> section and everything up till <div id="main">
 *
 * @package WordPress
 * @subpackage Twenty_Eleven
 * @since Twenty Eleven 1.0
 */
?><!DOCTYPE html>
<!--[if IE 6]>
<html id="ie6" <?php language_attributes(); ?>>
<![endif]-->
<!--[if IE 7]>
<html id="ie7" <?php language_attributes(); ?>>
<![endif]-->
<!--[if IE 8]>
<html id="ie8" <?php language_attributes(); ?>>
<![endif]-->
<!--[if !(IE 6) | !(IE 7) | !(IE 8)  ]><!-->
<html <?php language_attributes(); ?>>
<!--<![endif]-->
<head>
<link rel="shortcut icon" href="<?php bloginfo('stylesheet_directory'); ?>/favicon.ico" />
<meta charset="<?php bloginfo( 'charset' ); ?>" />
<title><?php
    /*
     * Print the <title> tag based on what is being viewed.
     */
    global $page, $paged;

    wp_title( '|', true, 'right' );

    // Add the blog name.
    bloginfo( 'name' );

    // Add the blog description for the home/front page.
    $site_description = get_bloginfo( 'description', 'display' );
    if ( $site_description && ( is_home() || is_front_page() ) )
        echo " | $site_description";

    // Add a page number if necessary:
    if ( $paged >= 2 || $page >= 2 )
        echo ' | ' . sprintf( __( 'Page %s', 'twentyeleven' ), max( $paged, $page ) );

    ?></title>
<link rel="profile" href="http://gmpg.org/xfn/11" />
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="all" href="<?php bloginfo( 'stylesheet_url' ); ?>" />
<link rel="pingback" href="<?php bloginfo( 'pingback_url' ); ?>" />
<!--[if lt IE 9]>
<script src="<?php echo get_template_directory_uri(); ?>/js/html5.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<![endif]-->
<?php
    /* We add some JavaScript to pages with the comment form
     * to support sites with threaded comments (when in use).
     */
    if ( is_singular() && get_option( 'thread_comments' ) )
        wp_enqueue_script( 'comment-reply' );

    /* Always have wp_head() just before the closing </head>
     * tag of your theme, or you will break many plugins, which
     * generally use this hook to add elements to <head> such
     * as styles, scripts, and meta tags.
     */
    wp_head();
?>

<script type="text/javascript"> 
/* Superior Web Systems */ 
function displayHideBox(boxNumber) 
{ 
    if(document.getElementById("LightBox"+boxNumber).style.display=="none") {
        document.getElementById("LightBox"+boxNumber).style.display="block";
        document.getElementById("grayBG").style.display="block"; 
    } else { 
        document.getElementById("LightBox"+boxNumber).style.display="none";
        document.getElementById("grayBG").style.display="none"; 
    } 
} 
</script> 
</head>

<body <?php body_class(); ?>>

<div id="page" class="hfeed">

<div id="header-bg">
    <header id="branding" role="banner">

<div class="view-basket"><a href="http://www.theshowroomonline.co.uk/view-basket">View Basket</a></div>
<div class="sign-in"><a href="http://www.theshowroomonline.co.uk/sign-in">Sign In</a><span style="color: #666">|</span></div>
                <h1 id="site-title"><a href="http://www.theshowroomonline.co.uk/"><img src="http://www.theshowroomonline.co.uk/wp-content/uploads/2013/05/logo.png" alt="The Showroom Online Logo"></a></h1>
                <h2 id="site-description"><?php bloginfo( 'description' ); ?></h2>

            <?php
                // Check to see if the header image has been removed
                $header_image = get_header_image();
                if ( ! empty( $header_image ) ) :
            ?>
            <a href="<?php echo esc_url( home_url( '/' ) ); ?>">
                <?php
                    // The header image
                    // Check if this is a post or page, if it has a thumbnail, and if it's a big one
                    if ( is_singular() &&
                            has_post_thumbnail( $post->ID ) &&
                            ( /* $src, $width, $height */ $image = wp_get_attachment_image_src( get_post_thumbnail_id( $post->ID ), array( HEADER_IMAGE_WIDTH, HEADER_IMAGE_WIDTH ) ) ) &&
                            $image[1] >= HEADER_IMAGE_WIDTH ) :
                        // Houston, we have a new header image!
                        echo get_the_post_thumbnail( $post->ID, 'post-thumbnail' );
                    else : ?>
                    <img src="<?php header_image(); ?>" width="<?php echo HEADER_IMAGE_WIDTH; ?>" height="<?php echo HEADER_IMAGE_HEIGHT; ?>" alt="" />
                <?php endif; // end check for featured image or standard header ?>
            </a>

            <?php endif; // end check for removed header image ?>

            <?php
                // Has the text been hidden?
                if ( 'blank' == get_header_textcolor() ) :
            ?>
                <div class="only-search<?php if ( ! empty( $header_image ) ) : ?> with-image<?php endif; ?>">
                <?php get_search_form(); ?>
                </div>

            <?php
                else :
            ?>
                <?php get_search_form(); ?>
            <?php endif; ?>

            <nav id="access" role="navigation">
                <h3 class="assistive-text"><?php _e( 'Main menu', 'twentyeleven' ); ?></h3>
                <?php /*  Allow screen readers / text browsers to skip the navigation menu and get right to the good stuff. */ ?>
                <div class="skip-link"><a class="assistive-text" href="#content" title="<?php esc_attr_e( 'Skip to primary content', 'twentyeleven' ); ?>"><?php _e( 'Skip to primary content', 'twentyeleven' ); ?></a></div>
                <div class="skip-link"><a class="assistive-text" href="#secondary" title="<?php esc_attr_e( 'Skip to secondary content', 'twentyeleven' ); ?>"><?php _e( 'Skip to secondary content', 'twentyeleven' ); ?></a></div>

                <?php /* Our navigation menu.  If one isn't filled out, wp_nav_menu falls back to wp_page_menu. The menu assiged to the primary position is the one used. If none is assigned, the menu with the lowest ID is used. */ ?>
                <?php wp_nav_menu( array( 'theme_location' => 'primary' ) ); ?>

            </nav><!-- #access -->


    </header><!-- #branding -->
</div>
    <div id="main">
```

[image: Free casino link as it appears on my site]

Comment: yes, you have been hacked

Comment: run `grep -r casino /path/to/your/wordpress/root/folder` to see if it is in the code, or do a db dump with `mysqldump` and then search there for the `casino`, to see if it is in the database

Comment: Post a copy of your `header.php`; the reason you're not finding the link was just a plain text search for "casino" is probably because it's using `base64_decode` or a similar method to reconstruct the obfuscated code.

Comment: Alternatively, your client machine could have a virus/malware of some sort, which adds it to the page you're viewing.

Comment: I have added the header.php code

Comment: Does the same unwanted link appear if you activate another theme?

Comment: I would go for disabling all the plugins, and re-enabling one-by-one. As the link is in the head, I think one of the plugins could be the culprit. (first bet goes to photospace)

Comment: Thank you. It seems mailchimp was causing the problem all along.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A friends wordpress site was recently hacked, I used this plugin http://wordpress.org/plugins/gotmls/ to get rid of the Malware. Hope this helps.